# HttpPostedFileBase null in production, but not test environment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 environments, which until today I thought were exactly the same. (sandbox & production)

I have a mobile device, posting a file to the server. This works fine in the sandbox environment, but when I run the same thing in production, the file is null. I have checked the web.config and `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="264768888" />`
is set to above in both environments. What am I missing here? What can be different? Could this be some setting in IIS? Code below:

The file I'm testing with is 64k.

**Server Code**

```
[HttpPost, Url("v3/organizations/{organizationId?}/SyncVideo/")]
public virtual void SyncVideo(HttpPostedFileBase file, Guid? organizationId) {
    if (file == null)
        throw new HttpBadRequestException("file is missing");

    if (organizationId.IsNull()) throw new HttpNotFoundExecption();
    if (organizationId != RESTContext.OrganizationId) throw new HttpNotAuthorizedException();

    var basePath = RESTContext.Config.VideoPath;

    //using (new Impersonator(RESTContext.Config.VideoPathUsername, RESTContext.Config.VideoPathDomain,
    //    RESTContext.Config.VideoPathPassword)) {
    //    if (!Directory.Exists(basePath))
    //        Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);
    //    file.SaveAs(basePath + @"\" + file.FileName);
    //}
}
```

**Client Code**

```
public void UploadFile(string url, string path) {
    Stream stream = null;
    HttpClient client = null;
    MultipartFormDataContent content = null;
    StreamContent streamContent = null;

    try {
        stream = Platform.FileSystem.ReadStreamFromFile(path);
        Platform.Console.WriteLine(stream.Length.ToString());
        client = new HttpClient();
        content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        foreach (var header in headers)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);

        streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);

        content.Add(streamContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(path));
        var message = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

        if (message.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            Platform.Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
            throw new Exception(message.ToString());
        }
    } finally {
        content.NullSafeDispose();
        client.NullSafeDispose();
        stream.NullSafeDispose();
        streamContent.NullSafeDispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your web.config differ on the machines? What about your form's rendered HTML?

Comment: @Dai the web.configs are 99% the same minus some connection strings and app settings. I am not using html to post the file, this is a mobile device doing it directly via an API call.

Comment: Hmm, verify that the `Content-Type` on the request from the client is correct.

Comment: It is, again, the client can connect to both prod and sandbox. Works in sandbox, not in prod. Same code.

Comment: did you try this `<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- maxAllowedContentLength is in Bytes not Kilobytes for IIS to accept the request.  -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>`

Comment: General advice: Use `using` and get rid of all those manual dispose operations.

Answer (score 2):

Installing .net framework 4.5.1 on the server fixed it. It only had 4.5 before. I'm sure why this worked, but it did...

Comment: I have the same issue. But, for some reasons, I cannot install new framework version in the server. Anything else you found later?